# Realistic terrain with geometry nodes but it reacts to placed objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am still learning geo nodes and need some help with realistic terrain generation.

The goal in the end is to have a plane that will make it appear that the cube is on sandy terrain, but directly underneath the cube the rocky terrain is missing and you can see a metal plate that was hidden by the terrain.

Step 1 of the project would first be to create a gradient, or a flat surface for the cube and a terrain around it, then a nice noisy weathered gradient would be important, but one thing at a time. Thanks for everybody with an idea.

[image]

Here is my node tree but I am not sure if there is a better way to get closer to what I want. I hope this helps:
[image]

Comment: do you mean you have some gn setup and it does not react as you wish? If yes, you should share this setup.

Comment: I am sorry I thought my way is so wrong it can´t be hepful but I added it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the selection input in the set position node for this. You need to [mix the positions like this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math/mix.html):
[image: A mix node mixing between a position and a position with its z modified by some noise]

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this into my setup but I still have a question, is it possible to scale the proximity distance down without scaling the cube?

Comment: If you tinker with the values of the Map Range-node and the Color Ramp-node it should be possible to tweak it. Sometimes it is easier to use a [Float Curve-node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math/float_curve.html) rather than the Color Ramp.